# How to register and resolve multiple components based on same service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have a cached repository that implements same interface of the real repository. i.e.

```
public class CachedLocationRepository : ILocationRepository
public class LocationRepository : ILocationRepository
```

How do I register both with `Autofac` and tell a certain service which component to use?

i.e. some components use the real, some use the cached version.

```
public class UseRealImpl : IUseRealImpl
{
    public UseRealImpl(ILocationRepository locationRepository) 
    {
    }
}

public class UseCachedImpl : IUseCachedImpl
{
    public UseCachedImpl(ILocationRepository cachedLocationRepository) 
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Keyed Service for that : [Named and Keyed Services](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html)

For example :

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<CachedLocationRepository>()
       .As<ILocationRepository>()
       .Keyed<ILocationRepository>(RepositoryType.Cached);
builder.RegisterType<LocationRepository>()
       .As<ILocationRepository>()
       .Keyed<ILocationRepository>(RepositoryType.Real);
```

Then you can register the `UseCachedImpl` using a parameter :

```
builder.RegisterType<UseCachedImpl>()
       .As<UseCachedImpl>()
       .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(ILocationRepository)
                     ,(pi, c) => c.ResolveKeyed<ILocationRepository>(RepositoryType.Cached));
```

Or use the `WithKeyAttribute`

```
public class UseCachedImpl 
{
    public UseCachedImpl([WithKey(RepositoryType.Cached)]ILocationRepository cachedLocationRepository) 
    {
    }
}
```

Or create a `Module` that will automatically add a parameter based on a condition, for example if the service implements some interface.